# Is there any method to create radio button in com.ibm.cics.server

Tags: java, cics

The java API for CICS is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.jcics.javadoc/overview-tree.html). Does anyone know if there any method to put a couple of radio buttons to a web form using this API?

Here's my code to create radio button

```
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.getHttpRequestInstance();
String msg = "ZEUSBANK ANTI-FRAUD CHECK BY SHE0008.<br> "
                    + "When investigation is complete. Tick the check box and submit.<br>";
String template = "<form><input type=\"radio\"> YES<br><input type=\"radio\"> NO<br></form>";
HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
Document doc = new Document();
doc.createText(msg);
doc.appendFromTemplate(template);
resp.setMediaType("text/plain");
resp.sendDocument(doc, (short)200, "OK", ASCII);
```

But when I run it on a browser, it print plain text and doesn't convert html tag.

Comment: updated, please see if you can help.

Comment: @cschneid I am aware of that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47764208/1) is what I was reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I just change media type from `text/plain` to `text/html` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already discovered, you needed to send the request with the `text/html` content type.

If you're planning to do more Java web-based work through CICS Java, you might want to investigate the embedded WebSphere Liberty. It adds support for Java EE features, which includes JSF, JSP and Servlets, which can make web development in Java a lot easier.

Comment: Or better still use WLP to write a back-end REST API and write the front-end using a modern JavaScript framework like React, Polymer or Vue. Those Java frameworks like JSP and JSF have seen better days.

Answer (score 0):

Tri,

I haven't used CICS for 15 years, so I doubt I'm an expert anymore.  But looking quickly at the API, it seems like all the presentation logic would be in your regular Java code.  You would then format appropriate messages and invoke the CICS API to update the server & get a response.

There doesn't seem to be any 'BMS-related' methods at all (which is a good thing).

The only 'field' method I see is com.ibm.cics.server.FormField but that only has get() methods, not set().

Are you just starting with Java CICS, or are you just stuck on this particular issue?  If you have some sample code of what you are trying, post it so we can see if anyone has any ideas.

HTH, Jim